# SSL connection to Kafka from SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have Kafka docker running with SSL with the following

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.0
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    volumes:
      - ./data/zookeeper/data:/data
      - ./data/zookeeper/datalog:/datalog
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.0
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9093:9093
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:19092,SSL://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH: 'required'
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME: 'certs/server.keystore.jks'
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS: 'certs/kafka_keystore_credentials'
      KAFKA_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS: 'certs/kafka_sslkey_credentials'
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME: 'certs/server.truststore.jks'
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS: 'certs/kafka_truststore_credentials'
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    volumes:
      - ./certs:/etc/kafka/secrets/certs
      - ./data/kafka1/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
```

And SpringBoot application.yml has

```
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      security:
        protocol: "SSL"
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9093
      group-id: group-tenant2-id
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      ssl:
        trust-store-location: classpath:client.truststore.jks
        trust-store-password: test123


    producer:
      security:
        protocol: "SSL"
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9093
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      ssl:
        trust-store-location: classpath:client.truststore.jks
        trust-store-password: test123
```

But then I am unable to connect from SpringBoot with the following error

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: Failed to process post-handshake messages
> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:370) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:313) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:123) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(SSLEngineImpl.java:736) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:691) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:506) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:482) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:679) ~[na:na]
> at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.read(SslTransportLayer.java:569) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
> at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:95) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
> at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:452) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
> at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:402) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
> at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:674) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
> at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:576) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
> at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:560) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:265) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:215) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:246) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.coordinatorUnknownAndUnready(ConsumerCoordinator.java:459) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:487) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1262) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1231) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1211) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
> at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1529) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
> at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1519) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
> at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1343) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
> at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1255) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.8.jar:2.8.8]
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

Connect to the Kafka using SSL from Offset Explorer was fine
[image]

Comment: Where is the spring boot application running? in your host or in the same docker network?

Comment: It is from my local computer. Docker is also local

Comment: I'm not familiar with configuring Kafka with SSL, but one thing you should at least do is change the mapped port in the docker-compose from 9092 to 9093 which is where the SSL connection is listening. Then if your app is running in your host and connecting to localhost:9093 it will at least hit the Kafka broker

Comment: Yes, you are correct. After exposing port 9093, I am hitting another error. Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I need to add key-store details in the client SpringBoot application

```
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      security:
        protocol: "SSL"
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9093
      group-id: group-tenant2-id
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      ssl:
        trust-store-location: classpath:client.truststore.jks
        trust-store-password: test123
        key-password: key123
        key-store-location: classpath:client.keystore.jks
        key-store-password: test123
    producer:
      security:
        protocol: "SSL"
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9093
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      ssl:
        trust-store-location: classpath:client.truststore.jks
        trust-store-password: test123
        key-password: key123
        key-store-location: classpath:client.keystore.jks
        key-store-password: test123
```